# What is the end of this cable?

Tags: cable, ps2

In the below image (from [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047EB3MY)), the "left" end (which I have labeled "A") is clearly two PS/2 ports.

**What is the "right" end (which I have labeled "B")?**
Does it connect directly to a motherboard?

[image: Cable]

The above is apparently Lenovo part number 43N9149, but I haven't been able to find an actual specification sheet for this part -- only third-party seller listings on Amazon, eBay, and the like.

**ADDENDUM**

I need to be able to use a PS/2 mouse with a Lenovo ThinkStation that I am considering. The particular system I am considering does not have a built-in PS/2 port, but Lenovo sells the above part as an add-on. The problem is, on my existing desktop (not Lenovo) I have tried external USB to PS/2 adapters (dongles) from third-parties, and I have experienced a significant latency issue when I connect a mouse to it.  I mean, cursor movement on my screen significantly and noticeably lags the physical movement of my mouse with such external dongles.  I'm hoping that the "B" end above has a faster connection than an *external* USB connection would have.

Comment: Thats totally not true @mins! USB and PS/2 are entirely different signals. All Devices that work with passive converters support both signals! You can't use any device supporting only PS/2 in a USB port with a passive "converter".

Comment: @Josef. I stand corrected. This is the device [which senses the host](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CDQQFjABOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digchip.com%2Fdata%2F613%2F613-00010-0-MTP805A.pdf&ei=uqiuUraSI4TBhAfYvoG4Aw&usg=AFQjCNGU3s2Ftv5M2BoZf53mYfKxIStXwQ&sig2=LKM-PnRhlhPmzjfVKDL1ow) it is connected to, and send the proper signal. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you intend to unplug/replug the PS/2 mouse to this connector?  (Your phrase "when I connect a mouse to it" prompts this question.  I hope you do not mean that you (dis-)connect the mouse while powered.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

B-end is a Lenovo-specific 7-pin PS/2 connector, which you connect straight to Lenovo motherboard. See 3rd image from this auction for the details:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lenovo-ThinkStation-ThinkCentre-FRU-43N9149-PS-2-Keyboard-Mouse-Cable-/251535857927

Comment: Thanks.  Could you look at the "addendum" I added in my original question and see what you think?

Comment: Avoid USB to PS/2 adapters, all of them are problematic. Just buy this cable from photo.

Answer (score 7):

This 7-pin connector goes to a header on a Lenovo motherboard marked `KB/MS` (keyboard/mouse), specifically for interfacing the motherboard to PS/2 ports.

[image: The header]

According to the [Lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkCentre-A-E-M-S-Series/Thinkcentre-M58-7360-CTO-KB-MS-mainboard-header-pinout/m-p/1705543#M12396), the pinout is as follows:

```
/-------\
|4|3|2|1|
| |7|6|5|
\-------/

Pin 1 - 5V
Pin 2 - CLK
Pin 3 - Data  [5V]
Pin 4 - GND
Pin 5 - 3.3V
Pin 6 - GND (noisy)
Pin 7 - Data  [5V]
```

There is no official spec available.

Answer (score 4):

It is the keyboard / mouse port for the computer. Yes, port B connects directly to the motherboard. Depending on the age of the computer, it could either connect to a USB connector or to serial controllers for the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: One reason that I asked this question is that I need to be able to use a PS/2 mouse with a Lenovo ThinkStation that I am considering.  The particular system I am considering does not have a built-in PS/2 port, but Lenovo sells the above part as an add-on.  The problem is, on my existing desktop I have tried *external* USB to PS/2 adapters (dongles) from third-parties, and I have experienced a significant latency issue when I connect a mouse to it.  If the above has a USB internal connector end, is there any chance I would experience less latency than with an external dongle?

Comment: Since they sell it as an add-on, it would work on your system. I'm not familiar with the ThinkStation's motherboard to be able to tell you about the latency.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a USB internal connector. It should connect to the motherboard in the same header as what you would connect the 'front' USB on your case.

[image: USB Headers]

Though, given that it is a lenovo specific adapter, it could be specifically designed for a motherboard in one of their machines. Just check that the pins lines up (there's a covered over hole on the adapter and a missing pin on the headers, they should line up.)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think it is a USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 internal connector? I know it might be impossible to say.

Comment: It's not 10-pin USB connector. It's 7-pin dual-PS/2 Lenovo-specific connector.

Comment: @TomaszKlim  So probably (at least ideally) I will not necessarily experience the same latency issues as I did with *external* USB to PS/2 adapters (dongles) from third parties?

Comment: When you force connect your 7-pin cable to this 10-pin connector, you won't experience any latency issues, because you'll burn your USB controller immediately :)

Comment: But seriously, PS/2 mouse will be faster, but USB mouse with vendor drivers can be more precise.

Comment: This answer is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

/-------\

|4|3|2|1|

|X|7|6|5|

-------/

Pin 1 - 5V (Keyboard & Mouse)

Pin 2 - Keyboard CLOCK

Pin 3 - Keyboard Data

Pin 4 - GROUND (Keyboard & Mouse)

Pin 5 - No connection

Pin 6 - Mouse CLOCK

Pin 7 - Mouse Data

Pin X - Connector Orientation KEY

Keyboard & Mouse mini-DIN-6 pinouts from http://www.burtonsys.com/PS2_keyboard_and_mouse_mini-DIN-6_connector_pinouts.html

Built from scrap parts and it works.

Comment: How is this answer different from oldmud0's?